# Angular 6 Material - Cannot read property 'navigateByUrl' of undefined

Tags: angular, menu, angular-material, angular6, multi-level

I am trying to install Material Design in my Angular 6 app. I added Navigation schematic using the command ng generate @angular/material:nav myNav.

I am using multi-level nested menu from http://plugins.codershood.info/#/plugins/ngmm-plugin.

When I compile and serve the app, the menu display is successful but when I click on any menu item to redirect to annother component, I am getting error as

```
Cannot read property 'navigateByUrl' of undefined
```

**My code for app.modules.ts is as follow:**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { LayoutModule } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { MatToolbarModule, MatButtonModule, MatSidenavModule, MatIconModule, MatListModule } from '@angular/material';
import { MyNavComponent } from './my-nav/my-nav.component';
import { NgMaterialMultilevelMenuModule } from 'ng-material-multilevel-menu';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MyNavComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    LayoutModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatListModule,
    NgMaterialMultilevelMenuModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**My code for my-nav.component.ts is as follow:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BreakpointObserver, Breakpoints } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-nav',
  templateUrl: './my-nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-nav.component.css'],
})
export class MyNavComponent {
    config = {
        paddingAtStart: true,
        classname: 'my-custom-class',
        listBackgroundColor: '#EEE',
        fontColor: 'rgb(8, 54, 71)',
        backgroundColor: 'FFF',
        selectedListFontColor: '#673AB7',
      };
    appitems = [
        {
           label: 'Dashboard',
           link: '/item-1-1',
           icon: 'dashboard'
        },
      {
        label: 'Dashboard',
        icon: 'dashboard',
        items: [
          {
            label: 'Item 1.1',
            link: '/item-1-1',
            faIcon: 'fab fa-accusoft'
          },
          {
            label: 'Item 1.2',
            faIcon: 'fab fa-accessible-icon',
            items: [
              {
                label: 'Item 1.2.1',
                link: '/item-1-2-1',
                faIcon: 'fas fa-allergies'
              },
              {
                label: 'Item 1.2.2',
                faIcon: 'fas fa-ambulance',
                items: [
                  {
                    label: 'Item 1.2.2.1',
                    link: 'item-1-2-2-1',
                    faIcon: 'fas fa-anchor'
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        label: 'Item 2',
        icon: 'alarm',
        items: [
          {
            label: 'Item 2.1',
            link: '/item-2-1',
            icon: 'favorite'
          },
          {
            label: 'Item 2.2',
            link: '/item-2-2',
            icon: 'favorite_border'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        label: 'Item 3',
        link: '/item-3',
        icon: 'offline_pin'
      },
      {
        label: 'Item 4',
        link: '/item-4',
        icon: 'star_rate',
        hidden: true
      }
    ];

    navTo($event) {
        let url = $event.link;
        this.router.navigateByUrl(url);
    }

  isHandset$: Observable<boolean> = this.breakpointObserver.observe(Breakpoints.Handset)
    .pipe(
      map(result => result.matches)
    );

  constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver) {}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to inject router in the constructor as follows,

```
  constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver, private router : Router) {}
```

Comment: after injecting router , it says `Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for MyNavComponent: ([object Object], ?).` Is it related to any kind of imports or exports?

Comment: can you post where you have imported Router

Comment: As you can check in the above given code, i have imported AppRoutingModule in app.modules.ts

Comment: did you import Router in the component?

Comment: No. How do import that?

Comment: import {  Router} from '@angular/router';

Comment: I have imported import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router'; in app-routing.module.ts

Comment: you need in the component as well

Comment: after integrating in component, I am getting one more error as `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'item-1-1'`

Comment: which means your routerConfig is not valid,, post the code

Comment: import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }

Comment: i see no routes defined there. thats the problem

Comment: That is because I am using dynamic routes. I am using this.router.navigateByUrl(url); to navigate to another route

Comment: whatever dynamic routes you are generating it should be there in the config. if not you will get the above error. please do the basics right

Comment: I added this const routes: Routes = [{ path: '/item-1-1', component: MyNavComponent }]; and not it showing me Uncaught ReferenceError: MyNavComponent is not defined

Comment: dude! this question's answer is provided above. now you are taking to too many directions. better to google errors before you ask. it means your component is not under declarations or imported

Comment: It is already there. You can check the above code which I posted in question

Comment: you would  not have imported in the router module

Comment: Already Added:
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { MyNavComponent } from './my-nav/my-nav.component';


const routes: Routes = [];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }

Answer (score 0):

converting it to arrow function works on my end, try 
from

```
navTo($event) {
```

to

```
navTo = ($event) => =  {
```